# ActionCable + Google Pub/Sub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, google-cloud-pubsub

I am deploying my Ruby on Rails web app to Google cloud and I would like to know if it could be possible to create a module that allows ActionCable to use Googles Pub/Sub([Link](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview)) instead of Redis or Postgres? ActionCable would publish and subscribe to events within Google Pub/Sub.

If you think it could be possible, could you point me in the right direction of a few resources on how I could develop such an extension for Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Google's pub/sub seems to use a REST API for everything (push, pull, publish). It doesn't seem to use Websockets and can be implemented without ActionCable. Google has a [Ruby client](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-pubsub/v0.25.0/google/cloud/pubsub) to help you.

Comment: @Myst I believe you can subscribe to it without polling?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you subscribe for Push notifications, the Google pub/sub service will send an HTTP request to your application. You just need to implement the route. I think Google has that in their docs somewhere, but you'll need to search for it. No Websockets are involved.

Comment: @Myst Okay, I understand, do you think its possible to create a module which interfaces with ActionCable? For example, make it so I don't need to specify routes but just specify the settings for ActionCable?

Comment: I don't think so... although maybe someone wrote a gem for that. I didn't search. Since these are two separate pub/sub systems, with slightly different semantics (i.e., no `subchannel`), you will need to write a bridge between them. It seems quite simple to write, for every message received from google, parse the channel and publish to ActiveCable. For every message you want to push, format the channel and push it using the google service (I think it will come back through the route google uses for pushing messages). Each Ruby process should probably subscribe as a google client.